# How to programmatically go to a UITableViewController from UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift2

can i know how to programmatically go to a `UITableViewController` from `UIViewController`

```
let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)      
let vc: UITableViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("showPlan") as! UITableViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Below is the error output from the debugger:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController
>   loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "showPlan" from
>   storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'

Comment: what the problem u faced, ur code is fine

Comment: Can you explain more your issue pls ?

Comment: it seems that a segue identifier which I have already commented out is being rendered.

Comment: Have you set you identifier to storyboard?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "showPlan" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'

Comment: have you set a table view in that controller?

Comment: Please make sure that your viewcontroller in storyboard is actually UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you set the `storyboard` identifier like this below image.

[image]

2. Let your `UITableViewController` class name is `MyTableVC`. Instantiate your VC like below.

.

```
 let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)      
let vc: MyTableVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("showPlan") as! MyTableVC
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

First do these two things then let me know what happened.

> Edit

Please ensure that your `VC` have `UINavigationController` because this approach is working properly here.

Comment: Tried still failed.